# Flutter Widget Test expansionTile not opening on tester.tap()

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am new to testing widgets in flutter and I have no clue why it doesn't work.
My expansionTile:

```
ExpansionTile(
        title: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
            child: Table(
              columnWidths: const <int, TableColumnWidth>{
                0: FlexColumnWidth(1),
                1: FlexColumnWidth(2.5),
                2: FlexColumnWidth(1),
              },
              children: [
                TableRow(children: [
                  Container(),
                  Container(TextButton(child: Text('Some title'))),
                  Container(),
                ])
              ],
            )),
        children: [
          Table(
            columnWidths: const <int, TableColumnWidth>{
              0: FlexColumnWidth(1),
              1: FlexColumnWidth(3),
              2: FlexColumnWidth(0.5),
            },
            children: <TableRow>[
              TableRow(children: [
                Container(),
                Container(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                    Text('Find me'),
                  ]),
                ),
                Align(),
              ]),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

And this is the test I have now:

```
testWidgets('Get opties text', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await _createWidget(tester);
  await tester.pump();

  await tester.ensureVisible(find.byType(ExpansionTile));
  await tester.tap(find.byType(ExpansionTile));
  await tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 15));
  await tester.ensureVisible(find.text('Find me')); //This gives me an error
});
```

Error:
The following StateError was thrown running a test:
Bad state: No element

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you've already resolved this issue, but if not try tapping on the ExpansionTile's title widget rather than the ExpansionTile itself. You can find by text or by key (if you add a key to the title).

Taken from how the Flutter team test ExpansionTiles:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/96f977f4df77f9f8069faa09062f58ba5836a9b5/packages/flutter/test/material/expansion_tile_test.dart#L123

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

also try this It's work for me

```
final icon = find.byIcon(Icons.expand_more).first; 
// if you have more then one ExpandablePanel then use .first.
expect(icon, findsOneWidget);
await tester.tap(icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was simply to add a delay after the tap like in the above link tests https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/96f977f4df77f9f8069faa09062f58ba5836a9b5/packages/flutter/test/material/expansion_tile_test.dart#L123

```
await tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 1));
```